# Is frame dragging expected to be quantized in a theory of quantum gravity?

Tags: black-hole, gravity, hawking-radiation, quantum-field-theory

Protons and electrons have angular momentum which is quantized. Would the angular momentum of black holes be quantized in quantum gravity? Would this then affect Hawking radiation?

Comment: A paper that seems relevant https://arxiv.org/abs/0906.1949 'Quantization of the black hole area as quantization of the angular momentum component'

Comment: It was interesting to read that rotating and non rotating black holes have the same quantization for area on the event horizon.